# WhatsApp Web automation with Selenium not working

Tags: python, selenium, whatsapp

I found [this python script on github](https://github.com/nosaevb/python-and-selenium-automate-whatsapp-web/blob/master/py_selenium_ian.py) that sends automatic WhatsApp Web messages through Selenium.

```
#https://www.github.com/iamnosa
#Let's import the Selenium package
from selenium import webdriver

#Let's use Firefox as our browser
web = webdriver.Firefox()
web.get('http://web.whatsapp.com')
input()

#Replace Mr Kelvin with the name of your friend to spam
elem = web.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(text(),"Mr Kelvin")]')
elem.click()
elem1 = web.find_elements_by_class_name('input')
while True:
    elem1[1].send_keys('hahahahahahaha')
web.find_element_by_class_name('send-container').click()
```

Even though it was meant for spamming, I was trying to adapt it for a good purpose, but the script as it stands doesn't seem to work. Instead of sending a message through WhatsApp Web, it simply loads a QR authentication screen and then it does nothing after I authenticate with my cellphone.

Any clue as to why this is happening? I'm running the lastest version of Selenium WebDriver on Firefox and geckodriver has already been extracted to /usr/bin/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realise this post is older, but it still seems to be frequently looked at.
The keystroke explanation of @vhad01 makes sense but did not work for me.

A simple dirty workaround that worked for me:
Replace `input()` with

```
import time
time.sleep(25)
```

while 25 is the amount of seconds it will be waited until the code will be further executed. (15 should also be sufficient to scan the QR code,...).

Answer (score 2):

The way I implement the scanning of the QR code is by detecting if the search bar is present or not on the page.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


chatlist_search = ".jN-F5.copyable-text.selectable-text"

web.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
WebDriverWait(web, 60).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, chatlist_search)))
```

This would wait until the chat search-bar is rendered on the page, or it will timeout in 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

This line :

```
input()
```

is waiting for a keystroke to continue.
Simply press any key after scanning.

Answer (score 0):

I was writing a selenium script to schedule my msgs and I came across your question. Yes, problem is that input() line. 
Instead of using input():

Use time.sleep(), no doubt it will work but better approach it to use implicit_wait(15)

Time.sleep() makes you wait even after scanning. The script totally stops till the given seconds.

In implicit_wait() the if element appear before specified time than script will start executing otherwise script will throw NoSuchElementException.

I used a more different method to whatsapp_login() and QR scanning. To see that my repo link: https://github.com/shauryauppal/PyWhatsapp

You would like this approach too.

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to scan the QR code hit return in the command line and the proceed further on your code.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')
print('Please Scan the QR Code and press enter')
input()
```

This is all you need and is also not very vague logic to apply to this problem.